# How to populate sub documents that exists in further sub objects

Tags: mongoose, populate

I have a Schema `storySchema` that has `chapters -> posts` that are not foreign documents, and `posts -> author` which is a foreign document. when i `populate({ path: "chapters", populate: { path: "posts", populate: {path: "author"}}})`, i get back 'undefined'.

I'm unsure how to use `populate` with subdocuments that aren't foreign.

`const storySchema = new Schema({
    chapters: [{
        title: String,
        description: String,
        posts: [{
            author: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "User"
            },
            description: String
        }]
    }],
});`

`models.Story.findOne({ _id: req.params.story_id }).populate({ path: "chapters", populate: { path: "posts", populate: { path: "author" } } })
            .then(story => {})...`

I expected to have a document with desired `author` field filled in, got undefined document instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing subfileds using [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

```
Story.findOne({ _id: req.params.story_id })
   .populate('chapters.posts.author")
   .then(story => {})
   .catch(err => err);
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried this earlier this morning, but the backend must not have updated because it didn't work then, yet now it works great. Aw well. Thanks much!